# What tool lets me see gzip's Huffman table and blocks?

Tags: compression, gzip, huffman-code

What tool lets me see the Huffman table that gzip and some other compression algorithms create?

I know that programs like bzip2 and zpaq use additional compression techniques, but I believe gzip, zip, and the lz family of programs use Huffman tables, and I would like to see these.

I realize that a given file may have multiple Huffman tables, one for each "block" of data.

Comment: Not really a programming problem.  But why do you need to see the tables?

Comment: I'm trying to create/find an algorithm that compresses multiple files well, where the files are highly redundant with each other, but a given single file isn't highly redundant. I want to do this WITHOUT tar-ring up the files into a single archive: I want to keep them separate. I believe seeing the gzip tables can help me do this. Since I am using this information to create a new problem I'm hoping it qualifies as a programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`infgen`](https://github.com/madler/infgen) will show you the dynamic block headers in some detail.  `infgen -d` will show you them in all their detail.

I don't know that that will help with what you are trying to do.  It sounds like what you're looking for are preset dictionaries.  In [zlib](http://zlib.net/) you can use `deflateSetDictionary()` and `inflateSetDictionary()` to provide up to 32K that effectively precedes the data to be compressed and provides source material in which to find matching strings.  If your files are similar, you may be able to construct a dictionary or more than one dictionary that is likely to have strings that match your data.

The Huffman tables are uniquely constructed to be optimal for each block, so it would reduce rather than improve compression to apply Huffman tables from a different block.